# Bittorrent MDHT responses

Tags: networking, protocols, bittorrent, dht, kademlia

What does the `'v'` key value correspond to in Bittorrent Mainline DHT (MDHT) responses?

Here's an example buncoded response:

```
{'y': b'r', 
 'r': {'id': b'\x9d\x97\xb5\x8cJ\x8c#\xf4PF\xe3|\xf3\t\xbb#\xdaj\\\xdc'},
 't': b'7/',
 'v': b'UT[\xf9'}
```

I can't find this key documented anywhere.

Here are my current sources on the protocol:

- [BEP 5: DHT Protocol](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html)
- [Kademlia: A Design Specification](http://xlattice.sourceforge.net/components/protocol/kademlia/specs.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'v'` indicates the **client name and version** ([according to this](http://git.deluge-torrent.org/deluge/tree/libtorrent/src/kademlia/dht_tracker.cpp?h=0.5-stable#n493))

```
UT: uTorrent
LT: libtorrent
MO: Mono Torrent
...etc
```

A **more complete list** of client identifiers can be [found here](http://lh-abc.googlecode.com/svn-history/r446/trunk/LMG/Utility/peerid.py)